# Mysqldump only comments without data

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

```
 mysqldump --defaults-extra-file="/home/user/.my.cnf" --all-databases --no-tablespaces -u user > /home/user/mysql-backup.sql
```

This used to work but for a few days it only dumps the comments without any table data.

I get this:

```
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 8.0.23, for Linux (x86_64)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: 
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   8.0.23

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!50503 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!50606 SET @OLD_INNODB_STATS_AUTO_RECALC=@@INNODB_STATS_AUTO_RECALC */;
/*!50606 SET GLOBAL INNODB_STATS_AUTO_RECALC=OFF */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */;
/*!50606 SET GLOBAL INNODB_STATS_AUTO_RECALC=@OLD_INNODB_STATS_AUTO_RECALC */;

/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;

-- Dump completed on 2021-04-05 20:00:01
```

If I do `mysqldump --defaults-extra-file="/home/user/.my.cnf" --databases database_name --no-tablespaces -u user > /home/user/mysql-backup.sql` it dumps the data correctly.

I don't know what changed, maybe I updated something in ubuntu but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Are you running this in a console where you can see error messages sent to stderr or through a script in some other context such as crontab?

Comment: I tried it in console I get no error and same behavior.

Comment: I have the impression that it's just not finding any database (which isn't an error from MySQL perspective) but I've no idea why. Have you changed something that might affect `user` permissions?

Comment: I don't think so, I think I might updated mysql version at some point. But what I don't understand is why is the same command working if I specify the database by name and isn't working when I use `all-databases`

Comment: For that to work, the user needs to get a list of what databases exist. In some circumstances you need the [`SHOW DATABASES` privilege](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-grants.html).